# Триггер для проверки пересекающиеся периодов времени во всех записях таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, инспекция-кода, plsql, триггер

Есть простая таблица расписания фильмов в кинотеатре:

```sql
CREATE TABLE seance (
    start_time            DATE NOT NULL, -- дата начала фильма (с точностью до минут)
    films_id_film         NUMBER(30) NOT NULL, -- идшник фильма, который будет идти
    cinema_hall_id_hall   NUMBER(30) NOT NULL -- идшник зала, в котором будет идти
    final_time            DATE NOT NULL -- дата окончания фильма (с точностью до минут)
);
ALTER TABLE seance
    ADD CONSTRAINT seance_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cinema_hall_id_hall,
                                           films_id_film,
                                           start_time,
                                           final_time );
```

**Задание**: *написать триггер, который не позволяет указывать в пересекающиеся периоды времени и в одном и том же зале разные фильмы*. То есть, если фильм с `films_id_film = 1` идет 01.01.1999 13:00 - 15:00 в зале с `cinema_hall_id_hall = 1`, то нельзя вставить фильм в таблицу с таким же ID зала, у которого дата начала показа будет, например, 01.01.1999 14:00.

Есть попытка решения, но все это не работает:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_seance
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SEANCE
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        realFinalDate DATE;
    BEGIN
            SELECT final_time INTO realFinalDate FROM SEANCE WHERE 
                films_id_film = :new.films_id_film
                AND cinema_hall_id_hall = :new.cinema_hall_id_hall
                AND trunc(start_time) = trunc(:new.start_time)
                AND start_time <> :new.start_time;

        IF realfinaldate > :new.start_time THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Добавление фильма в тот же зал в то же время недопустимо!!!'); 
        END IF;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: А с чем собственно говоря проблемы? Добавьте пример вашего триггера и кода вызывающего ошибку.

Comment: не могу написать непосредственно тело триггера

Comment: Просто сделайте [минимальный и самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) для вашей задачи. Например у меня нет желание делать триггер за вас. Однако я готов подсказать, как исправить. Или объяснить, почему он сейчас не работает

Comment: А триггер-то зачем? достаточно обычного check constraint.

Comment: Триггер for each row не может работать со своей таблицей. Нужен общий триггер (без for each), но он будет вынужден контролировать пересечения глобально по всей таблице. Если по скорости работы это не подходит, то нужно 2 триггера. Первый for each row, который сохранит в другую таблицу id изменяющихся записей. Второй на весь запрос (без for each row), который возьмет сохраненные id и проверит эти записи на пересечения, после чего удалит id, что бы вспомогательная таблица была всегда пустой.

Comment: довольно неплохо о [триггерах](https://habr.com/ru/post/256655/)

Comment: Хотя да, можно 2 триггера собрать в один campaund и хранить id меняющихся записей в какой нибудь коллекции, но принцип остается тот же, for each row запоминаем id, after statement используем их и проверяем пересечения

Comment: @Akina Как вы себе представляете такой check ?

Comment: @Mike Да, что-то я погорячился, Oracle не позволяет подзапросы в constraint, ни прямо, ни в функциях...

Answer (score 2):

Если по заданию - написать триггер, то можно решить так:

```sql
create or replace type seanceRow force as object (
    films_id_film number, cinema_hall_id_hall number, start_time date, final_time date,
    rid varchar2 (18))
/    
create or replace type seanceRows is table of seanceRow;
/
create or replace trigger check_seance for insert or update on seance compound trigger
    seances seanceRows := seanceRows ();
    rid rowid;
    sec constant number := 1/24*60*60; 
    after each row is begin  
        seances.extend;
        seances (seances.last) := seanceRow (
            :new.films_id_film, :new.cinema_hall_id_hall, :new.start_time, :new.final_time,
            rowidtochar (:new.rowid));
    end after each row; 
    after statement is begin 
        for r in (
            select /*+ first_fetch */
                o.films_id_film, o.cinema_hall_id_hall, o.start_time, o.final_time
            from table (seances) n  
            join seance o on (
                    o.cinema_hall_id_hall = n.cinema_hall_id_hall
                and o.rowid != chartorowid (n.rid)
                and o.start_time < n.final_time 
                and o.final_time > n.start_time)) loop
            raise_application_error (-20000, 
                'Добавление фильма в тот же зал в то же время недопустимо!'||
                chr(10)||'Уже идет в зале: '||r.cinema_hall_id_hall||' фильм '||r.films_id_film||
                ' с '||r.start_time||' до '||r.final_time);
        end loop;        
    end after statement;
end;
/
```

Попробовать так:

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format='hh24:mi';

insert into seance values ('13:00', 123, 101, '15:00'); --1 row inserted.   
insert into seance values ('15:00', 567, 101, '17:00'); --1 row inserted.   
insert into seance values ('16:00', 890, 101, '18:00');
Error report -
ORA-20000: Добавление фильма в тот же зал в то же время недопустимо!
Уже идет в зале: 101 фильм 567 с 15:00 до 17:00
```

---

**На заметку** Решение с триггером не самое лучшее, т.к. новые записи сначала будут добавлены и в случае ошибки удалены при откате. Это всё равно, что гводь в доску забить, а потом гвоздодёром его обратно выдирать. "Семь раз отмерь, потом забей" (ц).